# Java Recursion – Don’t quite understand the recursive methods

Tags: java, recursion

Learning Java at the minute. I’ve been asked to take an alphabetical string from user (can be any length/variation) assign a numeric value i.e. a=1, b=2 ....z=26 add the user input together using a recursive method. Not looking for a straight-out answer, just where I’ve gone wrong and a point in the right direction.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) {
        int result = sumUp(i) + convertToNum(str.charAt(i));

        System.out.print(result);
    }
}

static int convertToNum(char userIn) {
    int num = 0;
    if (userIn >= 'a' && userIn <= 'z') {
        num += 1 + userIn - 97;
    }
    return num;
}

static int sumUp(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    return (n % 10 + sumUp(n / 10));
}
```

Comment: The idea is that recursive methods will replace a `loop`.  Rather than looping and passing in a char, the idea is that you will pass in the `String` and recursively pass what is left of the `String`

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: The **sumUp()** method is a recursive method for taking each digit within the supplied method argument and summing them together. If 32848 is supplied to the method then 3 + 2 + 8 + 4 + 8 = the value of `25` is returned. I'm not really sure this is the intent. I think the task is: When a string is supplied, recursively sum up the Unicode value for each character within that string. So, "apple" would sum up to be: (a)97 + (p)112 + (p)112 + (l)108 + (e)101 = `530". Get the values or each character in the supplied string and sum them recursively.

Comment: What is the expected output for "abz"  ? Is it 1+2+26 = 29 ?

Comment: But would it be possible to do all of this within one method? So covert “apples” to Unicode, subtract 97 so a=1 p=16 p=16etc. then add each character in the string, so “apple” would return 1+16+16+12+5 = 50. 
I can figure out both parts individually. Where my issue is and for the life of me can’t wrap my head around, is that I’d like to be able to combine the convertToNum and sumUP into one recursive method and then call it to main.